# Sinatra example code to download a large file

Tags: sinatra

I started using sinatra,

Right now I'm using the following code to handle file downloads,
It works great for small files, but when it comes to large files > 500MB
The connection disconnects in the middle.

```
dpath = "/some root path to file"
get '/getfile/:path' do |path|
    s = path.to_s
    s.gsub!("-*-","/")
    fn = s.split("/").last
    s = dpath +"/"+ s
    send_file s,:filename => fn
end
```

Comment: Are any error codes returned by the client or the server log?

Comment: dpath- root path defined gobally

Comment: Maybe raise timeout error somewhere

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

What does your `validate` method do? If it's trying to open the file in memory, you might be running out of ram on your server (especially with large files).

Where are you setting `fn` ? It's a local variable inside the get scope and there's nothing setting it in your code example.

Comment: I have edited the code.. I'm using this in a small project. I would like to know whether my approach is correct.. Correct me if i'm wrong. Thank u